# Why is Spain men's national football team nicknamed La Roja?

Tags: sustantivos, adjetivos, género

Spain men's national football team is nicknamed La Roja.

But we know that the gender of an adjective should be the same with its noun. So why is it feminine while it is about a **men's** team?

Also, why is it singular? A team is a bunch of players. So shouldn't the nickname have been plural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El sobrenombre proviene de la tradición que existe en algunos países de conocer a su selección nacional por el color de la camiseta que ésta utiliza. Así pues, cuando se habla de "La Roja", se esta refiriendo a la camiseta que utilizan los jugadores, como unidad o en su conjunto ya que hace referencia a todos ellos como equipo, excepto el portero que puede ir vestido de forma diferente. "La camiseta Roja", "La Roja". Se utiliza el singular y no el plural ya que se entiende que "**la selección**" es singular y la camiseta, de genero femenino, que lleva la selección es "**la camiseta roja**". "**La** camiseta **Roja**", "**La Roja**".

Historia y Controversia

El nombre de "**La Roja**" para la selección española es relativamente reciente y se le atribuyen a las palabras pronunciadas por el seleccionador Luis Aragonés en 2004, cuando dijo" **Me gustaría que la selección tuviera un nombre, una identidad. Igual que Brasil es la Canarinha o Argentina la Albiceleste, me gustaría que España fuera **La Roja****.

Esto provocaría posteriormente un enfrentamiento polémico con la selección chilena que también es conocida por "La Roja" y cuyo uso, como apodo o sobrenombre, es bastante anterior al de la selección española.

Comment: Sounds your answer has a source.

Answer (score 2):

User Diego has already given you the reason, that it agrees with an unstated noun, *la selección*, typically used for a national team but note that if it were a club team the unstated noun would be more likely to be *el equipo* or *el club* so you would see *el Real Madrid*. The sex of the players is immaterial of course.

Having said all that if you want to refer to a club team using its nickname then things are different [Real Madrid](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Madrid_Club_de_F%C3%BAtbol) are known as *los blancos* or *los merengues* since they play in white and their historical rivals [FC Barcelona](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BAtbol_Club_Barcelona) are known as *los azulgranas* from their blue and red shirt colours. (In Catalan *blaugranas*.). The [Real Madrid Women](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Madrid_Club_de_F%C3%BAtbol_(femenino)) are known as *las blancas* so in this case the adjectives do agree with the sex of the players.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25216)

Comment: @FGSUZ I was trying to explain to the OP that there are two situations here, the national team and club teams. Their reasoning was partly correct if they were talking about clubs.